# How to calculate the number of trials for a 'meaningful' result

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

Apologies for newbie question but have failed to understand what I've read about in this area so pointers to the correct methods would focus my attention.

I have a piece of software which when tested repeatedly in the same way fails occasionally - say once in 20 runs.

If I make a change to fix the problem, how many times should I test it to be confident (say 95%) that the changed software is actually better than the original.

More generally: if a test fails a out of b times. After the **fix**, how many times (c) must it run without any failures to be confident to d%.

Comment: This is still niggling me and I didn't feel satisfied by the 2 answers given - my apologies to Greg & Thomas.
Don't know if this is correct but I've experimented with simply calculating the binomial distribution.

Comment: Oops - missed editing deadline...

I don't know if this is correct but I've experimented with simply calculating the binomial distribution - i.e. (n! / ((n-k)! k!)) p^k (1-p)^(n-k) where n = number of trials, k = number of failures, p = probability of failure.

In my current problem, the buggy code gave me 3 failures in 9 trials - let's assume this implies a probability of 1/3. Chance of 0 fails in 9 is 2.6%, better still 0 fails in 15 trials is 0.23%. That gives me a feeling for it.

Answer (score 4):

A rule of thumb says that if you run n trials and see no events, then the 95% confidence interval for the rate of the events is from 0 to 3/n.  So if you want to be 95% confident that the true proportion of failures is below p, then do 3/p runs and if none fail, you can be 95% confident that the proportion is below p.

Comment: (+1) This answers one variant of the question, which interprets "fix" to mean "eliminate entirely": it finds (approximately) the power to distinguish a 0% failure rate from a $100 p$% failure rate.  That is why the sample size is much smaller than those estimated by @Thomas Levine, who interprets "fix" in the sense of "better than the original," (but maybe not perfect).

Comment: How do we adjust this for varying the value of 95%? Eg, that would mean that 1/20 Jira tickets would be reopened. Can we adjust this to 99.5% and see how costly that would be?

Comment: Missed edit deadline, but I ran some numbers and it seems like 5/p gives >99% confidence, but I cannot justify this formally

Answer (score 3):

You have to guess what the new failure rate is going to be (maybe based on a pilot study) and then calculate the chance of type II error.

There are [formulae for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power#Example), but I sometimes find it easier and more convincing to simulate the results. Here's some sloppy R code that will use simulations to estimate the power. (The link is for a paired t-test, and I simulated a two-sample t-test, so you'd have to adjust one of these for them to be equivalent.)

```
#Compare the failure rates of two random samples
fail <- function(n,p) rbinom(n,1,p)
#It would be good to change t.test to a more powerful test (and see how that affects power).
compare <- function (n,p.old=1/20,p.new=1/10) t.test(fail(n,p.old),fail(n,p.new))$p.value

#Use 50 simulations. Increase this for higher precision
simulations<-50

#Parametrize sample size
samplesize<-seq(50,1000,10)
#What's the 95%ile p-value of the simulations
q95_p.value<-function(samplesize) quantile(replicate(simulations,compare(samplesize)),0.95)

#Plot the p-values
plot(samplesize,sapply(samplesize,q95_p.value),ylim=0:1,ylab='95%ile simulated p-value')
#If the 95%ile p-value for the sample size is below the line, then power is probably above 95%
abline(h=0.05)
```

Here is the resulting plot assuming that the old failure rate is $\frac{1}{20}$ and the new $\frac{1}{10}$. If the 95%ile p-value for the sample size is below the line, then power is probably above 95%.

[image: Plot of simulated p-values]

There's probably an R package that does this better.

And I must say that those sample sizes look awfully large. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: It's the right idea and the sample sizes should be large.  You would get insight into why by actually computing the power curve rather than simulating it.  Be careful in your choice of example: I don't think anybody would take a new failure rate of $1/10$ to be an improvement over $1/20$! :-)

Comment: Oh oops. Well let's pretend you're an evil mastermind who is trying to trip people up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is

Number of trials = log(1-CF)/log(1-failure rate),

where CF is the confidence factor you are looking for.

For your example, where you want a confidence of 95% that you solved a problem that is expected to occur 5% of the time, it would be

Number of trials = log(1-.95)/log(1-.05) = 59 trials rounding up.

Comment: Many thanks for that formula. Can you offer any references where I could read up on its derivation please